# How to test type of an object in Python?

Tags: python, types

```
import string
print string.ascii_lowercase # abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
print type(string.ascii_lowercase) # <type 'str'>
print string.ascii_lowercase is str # False
```

Shouldn't it be `True`?

Comment: Which version of Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `is` operator compares the identity of two objects. This is what I believe it does behind the scenes:

```
id(string.ascii_lowercase) == id(str)
```

Actual strings are always going to have a different identity than the type `str`, so this will always be `False`.

Here is the most Pythonic way to test whether something is a string:

```
isinstance(string.ascii_lowercase, basestring)
```

This will match both `str` and `unicode` strings.

Comment: Thanks for the id() example, got it now! :)

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
>>> isinstance('dfab', str)
True
```

`is` intended for identity testing.

Comment: +1 http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=isinstance#isinstance "Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct or indirect) subclass thereof."

Answer (score 2):

`string.ascii_lowercase is str` should not be `True`.

`type(string.ascii_lowercase) is str` is `True`.

The `is` keyword checks object identity, not type.

You may have seen code like `foo is None` often and thought that `None` is a type. `None` is actually a singleton object.

Comment: Oh, why not? any technical reason that I must know?

Comment: because `string.ascii_lowercase` is a string, whereas `str` is a type.

Comment: `is` test's whether they are the same object. i.e. they are both pointers to an object, are those objects the same.

Comment: See what happens when you do `type(str)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want `type(string.ascii_lowercase) is str` ?